# Lyx: How to make multiple lines on the lowertitleback (koma-script)

Tags: lyx

I am trying to use uppertitleback and lowertitleback in lyx (2.0.0)

If I just use uppertitleback and lowertitleback with one line apiece, it works just as expected.

However, if I put any text in between the uppertitleback and lowertitleback, then the entire lowertitleback ends up on the top of the next page.

What I want is the following in lowertitle back:
Copyright Statement
ISBN number

Any suggestions???  (I tried changing my page size back to default, but that didn't make a difference.)

Thank you before I pull out more of my hair!!

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that you need to insert a line break (I used a ragged line break) between each line so it passes it to LaTeX as all one paragraph.   Arrrrggghhhh!